# Visual studio 2010 setup projects always expand

Tags: visual-studio-2010

If I have a setup project in a VS 2010 solution and I add/remove another project, or unload/reload another project any setup projects in the solution are expanded in the solution explorer. It only does this for setup projects and it is extremely annoying. Is there any way to disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know whether or not there is a way to disable this behavior, but you can hide it in a solution folder. Just right click the solution, click Add -> New Solution Folder and then drag and drop the setup project into it. It won't expand automatically from there.